# unable to check out source code from gerrit.hyperledger.org

Tags: gerrit, hyperledger, ssh-keygen, hyperledger-fabric

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Gerrit/lf-account/
I've been using this for my setup and finished Configuring Gerrit to Use SSH. When I try to clone/check out the Source Code i get this error:

**Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

I'm not able to clone it, any fixes or ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: Your SSH key probably isn't accepted anymore. Did you change your local setup?

Comment: have you, by any chance, modified, or deleted any file from `~/.ssh` directory ?

Comment: i removed the .ssh directory and did the steps again and it worked from home directory. previously i was trying to pull from a directory which wasn't my home directory, but the ssh key files were present in the home dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something wrong with your SSH key. Check the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in your $HOME/.ssh directory and the id_rsa.pub configured in the Gerrit server. Execute the following command to help to find out what's going on:

```
ssh -vvv -p 29418 <user>@<gerrit-server>
```

Comment: yep i executed the comment and it said Incorrect RSA1 identifier. i want to clone the source code into a directory which isn't my home. not able to do it because .ssh is generated in my home directory

Comment: Actually you can execute the clone command in any directory you want. If you are having issues with this you can try to execute the clone at $HOME adding the desired directory as the last "git clone" parameter. See the "<directory>" parameter at the "git help clone" command.